Expect module: end of string is correctly matched, but characters remain in 'after' part, causing next expect to continue prematurely
I am writing a Perl script with the Expect module, where sometimes expects continues too early, because it matches a prompt of a previous command's output.
To illustrate the problem, I created a simple example script as per below:
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use Expect;

# disable Expect multiline matching (/m)
$Expect::Multiline_Matching = 0;

my $spawn = new Expect;
my $pattern = qr{[\r\n]+[^\r\n<]+[#>%] ?$};

# silence regular output:
$spawn->log_stdout(0);

# enable internal debug:
$spawn->exp_internal(1);

# spawn process (here: open serial console via picocom):
$spawn->spawn("picocom --baud 9600 --flow n /dev/ttyS8") or die "Cannot spawn picocom: $!\n";

# wait for output of spawned process to settle down:
$spawn->expect(2, [qr{.+}s => sub { exp_continue; } ], );

# send 2x newline ("enter") for demonstration of the problem:
$spawn->send("\n\n");

# wait for $pattern in response of spawned process
$spawn->expect(10, '-re', $pattern);

# cleanup (close picocom)
$spawn->send("\x01\x11");
$spawn->expect(10, '-re', qr/Thanks for using picocom/);
$spawn->hard_close();

Snippet from debug output:
Sending '\n\n' to spawn id(3)
 at /usr/share/perl5/Expect.pm line 1421.
        Expect::print(Expect=GLOB(0x17a5210), "\x{a}\x{a}") called at ./tmp.pl line 24
Starting EXPECT pattern matching...
 at /usr/share/perl5/Expect.pm line 597.
        Expect::expect(Expect=GLOB(0x17a5210), 10, "-re", qr([\r\n]+[^\r\n<]+[#>%] ?$)) called at ./tmp.pl line 27
spawn id(3): list of patterns:
  #1: -re `(?^:[\\r\\n]+[^\\r\\n<]+[#>%] ?$)'


spawn id(3): Does `'
match:
  pattern #1: -re `(?^:[\\r\\n]+[^\\r\\n<]+[#>%] ?$)'? No.


spawn id(3): Does `\r\n\r\n{mas'
match:
  pattern #1: -re `(?^:[\\r\\n]+[^\\r\\n<]+[#>%] ?$)'? No.


spawn id(3): Does `\r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\n'
match:
  pattern #1: -re `(?^:[\\r\\n]+[^\\r\\n<]+[#>%] ?$)'? No.


spawn id(3): Does `\r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\nroot@rou'
match:
  pattern #1: -re `(?^:[\\r\\n]+[^\\r\\n<]+[#>%] ?$)'? No.


spawn id(3): Does `\r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\nroot@router> \r\n\r'
match:
  pattern #1: -re `(?^:[\\r\\n]+[^\\r\\n<]+[#>%] ?$)'? No.


spawn id(3): Does `\r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\nroot@router> \r\n\r\n{master'
match:
  pattern #1: -re `(?^:[\\r\\n]+[^\\r\\n<]+[#>%] ?$)'? No.


spawn id(3): Does `\r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\nroot@router> \r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\nroo'
match:
  pattern #1: -re `(?^:[\\r\\n]+[^\\r\\n<]+[#>%] ?$)'? No.


spawn id(3): Does `\r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\nroot@router> \r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\nroot@router'
match:
  pattern #1: -re `(?^:[\\r\\n]+[^\\r\\n<]+[#>%] ?$)'? No.


spawn id(3): Does `\r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\nroot@router> \r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\nroot@router> '
match:
  pattern #1: -re `(?^:[\\r\\n]+[^\\r\\n<]+[#>%] ?$)'? YES!!
    Before match string: `\r\n\r\n{master:0}'
    Match string: `\r\nroot@router> '
    After match string: `\r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\nroot@router> '
    Matchlist: ()

What would I expect: an empty "After match" string:
After match string:`'

This residue in the actual "After match" string:
After match string:`\\r\\n\\r\\n{master:0}\\r\\nroot@router\> '

would lead to a premature expect match if I do another send/expect call.
Multiline Matching is disabled, which seems to work correctly, otherwise the match would have occured earlier, would it not?
Edit: after reading the first replies to my question: I tend to think that this is not a regexp issue, my pattern works as intended, which is confirmed by the exp_internal output; the "YES!!", indicating the successful match is exactly where I expect it to be, anchored to the end-of-string. It is the matching result that seems weird. Almost like a bug?

@brian d foy: the "exp_internal" debug output shows what the other side is outputting, it is "" as in "spawn id(3): Does `' match:". Regarding waiting/sleeping: my expectation of anchoring the pattern to the end-of-string is actually that expect waits "for some time" to catch up; I have to admin though that I do not know how expect actually determines how long "for some time" is appropriate.

The proper way to mark a Question as Solved is by checking the mark next to an Answer. It can be your own Answer.

I wrote the same example script in native tcl expect, and there it behaves differently (and as intended).
The tcl expect example script:
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

exp_internal 1
log_user 0

set pattern {[\r\n]+[^\r\n<]+[#>%] ?$}

# spawn process (here: open serial console via picocom):
spawn picocom --baud 9600 --flow n /dev/ttyS8

# wait for output of spawned process to settle down:
expect -timeout 2 -re {.+} exp_continue

# send 2x newline ("enter"):
send "\n\n"
expect -re $pattern

send_user "Anything left in the buffer?\n"
expect -timeout 2 -re {.+} exp_continue

send "\x01\x11"
expect "Thanks for using picocom"
close

Relevant debug output:
send: sending "\n\n" to { exp4 }
Gate keeper glob pattern for '[\r\n]+[^\r\n<]+[#>%] ?$' is ''. Not usable, disabling the performance booster.

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "[\r\n]+[^\r\n<]+[#>%] ?$"? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=no

expect: does "\r\n\r\n{mas" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "[\r\n]+[^\r\n<]+[#>%] ?$"? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=no

expect: does "\r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "[\r\n]+[^\r\n<]+[#>%] ?$"? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=no

expect: does "\r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\nroot@rou" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "[\r\n]+[^\r\n<]+[#>%] ?$"? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=no

expect: does "\r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\nroot@router> \r\n\r" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "[\r\n]+[^\r\n<]+[#>%] ?$"? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=no

expect: does "\r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\nroot@router> \r\n\r\n{master" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "[\r\n]+[^\r\n<]+[#>%] ?$"? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=no

expect: does "\r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\nroot@router> \r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\nroo" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "[\r\n]+[^\r\n<]+[#>%] ?$"? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=no

expect: does "\r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\nroot@router> \r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\nroot@router" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "[\r\n]+[^\r\n<]+[#>%] ?$"? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=no

expect: does "\r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\nroot@router> \r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\nroot@router> " (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "[\r\n]+[^\r\n<]+[#>%] ?$"? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "\r\nroot@router> "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\nroot@router> \r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\nroot@router> "
Anything left in the buffer?
Gate keeper glob pattern for '.+' is ''. Not usable, disabling the performance booster.

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression ".+"? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=no
expect: timed out

The expect_out(buffer) is the equivalent of the concatinated "Before" and "match" in the perl's version debug output; in contrast to the perl version, the match result contains everything up to the anchor at end-of-string, and not only the match up the first end-of-line; the rest of the buffer is empty, thus the timeout of the following expect .+ call.
I think my initial problem is a bug in the perl expect I currently use.
~$ dpkg -l|egrep expect
ii  expect                        5.45.4-2+b1                    i386         Automates interactive applications
ii  libexpect-perl                1.35-2                         all          Perl Expect interface
ii  tcl-expect:i386               5.45.4-2+b1                    i386         Automates interactive applications (Tcl package)
~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:        12
Codename:       bookworm
~$

So I might be affected by this bug:
https://github.com/jacoby/expect.pm/issues/10
Edit2: I downloaded the patched Expect.pm from the creator of the above mentioned github issue, and it solves my problem:
Sending '\n\n' to spawn id(3)
 at /usr/share/perl5/Expect.pm line 1413.
        Expect::print(Expect=GLOB(0x1681210), "\x{a}\x{a}") called at ./tmp.pl line 24
Starting EXPECT pattern matching...
 at /usr/share/perl5/Expect.pm line 597.
        Expect::expect(Expect=GLOB(0x1681210), 10, "-re", qr([\r\n]+[^\r\n<]+[#>%] ?$)) called at ./tmp.pl line 27
spawn id(3): list of patterns:
  #1: -re `(?^:[\\r\\n]+[^\\r\\n<]+[#>%] ?$)'


spawn id(3): Does `'
match:
  pattern #1: -re `(?^:[\\r\\n]+[^\\r\\n<]+[#>%] ?$)'? No.


spawn id(3): Does `\r\n\r\n{mas'
match:
  pattern #1: -re `(?^:[\\r\\n]+[^\\r\\n<]+[#>%] ?$)'? No.


spawn id(3): Does `\r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\n'
match:
  pattern #1: -re `(?^:[\\r\\n]+[^\\r\\n<]+[#>%] ?$)'? No.


spawn id(3): Does `\r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\nroot@rou'
match:
  pattern #1: -re `(?^:[\\r\\n]+[^\\r\\n<]+[#>%] ?$)'? No.


spawn id(3): Does `\r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\nroot@router> \r\n\r'
match:
  pattern #1: -re `(?^:[\\r\\n]+[^\\r\\n<]+[#>%] ?$)'? No.


spawn id(3): Does `\r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\nroot@router> \r\n\r\n{master'
match:
  pattern #1: -re `(?^:[\\r\\n]+[^\\r\\n<]+[#>%] ?$)'? No.


spawn id(3): Does `\r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\nroot@router> \r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\nroo'
match:
  pattern #1: -re `(?^:[\\r\\n]+[^\\r\\n<]+[#>%] ?$)'? No.


spawn id(3): Does `\r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\nroot@router> \r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\nroot@router'
match:
  pattern #1: -re `(?^:[\\r\\n]+[^\\r\\n<]+[#>%] ?$)'? No.


spawn id(3): Does `\r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\nroot@router> \r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\nroot@router> '
match:
  pattern #1: -re `(?^:[\\r\\n]+[^\\r\\n<]+[#>%] ?$)'? YES!!
    Before match string: `\r\n\r\n{master:0}\r\nroot@router> \r\n\r\n{master:0}'
    Match string: `\r\nroot@router> '
    After match string: `'
    Matchlist: (`')


I posted this both to the github issue tracker and the expect.pm mailinglist. I am not sure however if this reaches the maintainer at all.
https://sourceforge.net/p/expectperl/mailman/expectperl-discuss/thread/CAANFoXMx2qBXXv4P%3DqpwkXUw_yBJZMiNe3%3DHoOrOCUVxWZ4xVg%40mail.gmail.com/#msg58849528
https://github.com/jacoby/expect.pm/issues/10

When you are expecting, you always need to take care of the prompt. Anchoring the prompt at end of string normally is sufficient to wait for the last prompt, even if there are many in the buffer.
It looks like you have a 2 line prompt, so
my $prompt = qr/\r\n[^\r]+\r\nroot@router> $/;

$spawn->spawn("picocom ...") or die "Cannot spawn picocom: $!\n";

# wait for output of spawned process to settle down:
$spawn->expect(2, '-re'. $prompt );

$spawn->send("some command\r");

$spawn->expect(2, '-re', $prompt);

Then the command output would be in $before_match.
It's been a long time since I've used perl Expect, so I might have the details wrong.

"qr{[\r\n]+[^\r\n<]+[#>%] ?$}" DOES anchor at the end-of-string (by the dollar sign). The 'YES !!' in the debug output even indicates that it works as intended - only the matching result seems messed up.

First, $Expect::Multiline_Matching should have no effect when you pass in a regexp object (qr//). But then your pattern has not set "m", too, so it should be all the same.
So $ should anchor your regexp to the end of the whole string.
Your regexp is also not anchored to the beginning of the string, either.
(?^:[\\r\\n]+[^\\r\\n<]+[#>%] ?$) does not match the first \r\n\r\n{master:0} because what follows is neither '#', '>', nor '%'.
So matching starts again after it and succeeds with \r\nroot@router> , leaving what we see above as "After match string".
But I do not understand why it does not skip over this potential match either, as it is not located at the end of the whole string.
Can you try again after changing this:
# wait for $pattern in response of spawned process
$spawn->expect(10, '-re', $pattern);

into this:
# wait for $pattern in response of spawned process\
$spawn->expect(10, $pattern);

As far as I understand it, you pass in either a string and turn it into a regexp by prefixing it with '-re' or a regexp object.

"But I do not understand why it does not skip over this potential match either" - thanks for confirming my confusion. I do not think the pattern is passed to expect incorrectly, because the pattern that is used in exp_internal debug looks fine. I did try your suggestion anyway, but it results in an error: "expect(): Unknown pattern ref (?^:[\r\n]+[^\r\n<]+[#>%] ?$) at ./tmp.pl line 27."
